# How to do both is not null and a not in statement in sql (oracle)?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to say the statement

```
where date_end not in (null, 229)
```

I have already tried

```
where date_end not in (229) and date_end is not null
```

I have also tried

```
where date_end is not null or date_end not (229)
```

This is necessary because I am using the `date_end` in a `to_date` statement to create a date. I want to ignore 229 because of leap years and nulls because it will not respond in the `to_date` statement.

Comment: Your first version - `where date_end not in (229) and date_end is not null` should have worked (though `!= 229` is better than `not in (229)`), at least if the column is a number. What happened when you tried these, and what data are you querying? Sample data and table structures are useful things to include in your question, along with your full query, or a representative version of it if it's big. If 229 is supposed to represent Feb 29th and the column is a date then comparing it with a number doesn't make much sense.

Comment: The way the month/day is stored is as a number which puts a damper in things. But when I try the first way it says there is a problem with the query. I have looked through the other dates and there is not anything that could be causing a problem

Comment: "it says there is a problem" - please edit your question to show us the actual error you get, and the full query. We can't guess what is wrong, we need to see what you are doing and what happens. The fragment you showed looks OK - [here's an example of it working](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9301befba7dd38c0cd02b117197cf8aa).

Comment: your date_end is of which datatype??and moreover how are your comparing date_end  with 229 if its date ??? post results outcome with tables.

Answer (score 4):

You can try:

```
where NVL(date_end, 229) != 229
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply write:

```
where date_end <> 229
```

This also filters out `NULL` values.

The same is true for `not in`:

```
where date_end not in (229)
```

If you want to be explicit, use `and`:

```
where date_end <> 229 and date_end is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

This will be a better option in case there are other non-null values than 229.

```
(    where date_end is  null and  date_end  not in (229));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
where date_end not in ( 229 )
```

`NULL NOT IN ( 229 )` always evaluates to NULL, which is equivalent to FALSE in WHERE clause. Additional NOT NULL checking is needless.
Please examine a simple demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/358b6e/2

```
CREATE table test(
  date_end int
);

INSERT ALL
INTO test VALUES( null )
INTO test VALUES( 229 )
INTO test VALUES( 123 )
SELECT null FROM dual;
```

---

```
SELECT * FROM test;

| DATE_END |
|----------|
|   (null) |
|      229 |
|      123 |
```

---

```
SELECT * FROM test
WHERE date_end NOT IN ( 229 )

| DATE_END |
|----------|
|      123 |
```

Answer (score 0):

this has worked for me see if it works for you:

```
where date_end <>229 and date_end  is not null;
```